# How to become a Feed Administrator in Azure DevOps Artifacts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-artifacts

I can't seem to find out how to become a Feed Administrator for Artifacts.

Even the main administrator account doesn't have the permission of the Feed Administrator.

[image: artifacts]

According to the documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops

I should see this icon
[image: artifacts settings]

But I don't have it even in the main administrator account.

Comment: I have the same problem.
I am even listed as Owner of the feed, and I am also added to the Project Collection Administrators

Comment: @Herbert I managed to show it by adding the user in the Collection Administrators group and also some other groups and make sure you are on the correct organization settings because different organizations have different settings.

Comment: Might be good I add my solution too. Switching off the preview feature for feeds did the trick for me. See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/only-feed-administrators-can-edit-the-fe/10330619?q=only+feed+administrators+can+edit+the+feed